# In Gerry Anderson's UFO, were the moonbase officers ordinary human beings in costumes, or something else?

Tags: ufo

The Gerry Anderson TV series *UFO* featured a group of officers who manned the deep space radar systems.

They were all young and female. They wore identical costumes and distinctive makeup and had purple hair that was styled in the exact same way. (See picture below).

The effort seemed to have been taken to make them seem unique or mysterious, and they were set apart from the other female characters who dressed normally and had normal mannerisms.

[image: photograph of the described characters]

In-universe, were these characters supposed to be ordinary human beings, merely dressed up in an unusual way for some reason (if so, what?), or were they supposed to be something else, such as robots, aliens, or clones?

Is this ever discussed in the series, such as there being an origin or spotlight episode for them, or in any official sources such as a guidebook or novelization?

Comment: Highly related - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31537/whats-the-reason-for-the-purple-hair-on-the-british-1969-70-television-series

Comment: I was going more of an in universe answer. Rather than behind the scenes.

Comment: No such explanation exists. - https://ufoseries.fandom.com/wiki/Universe#Look_of_the_show

Comment: Then that in itself is an answer. There is nothing canon to set them apart form other crew memebers.

Answer (score 14):

I believe that they are normal human beings and the purple wigs are just a part of their uniform.

From the [UFO fandom website](https://ufoseries.fandom.com/wiki/Gay_Ellis) you can see a picture of Lt Ellis without the wig:

[image: Lt Gay Ellis]

Lt Ellis was the commander of the moonbase and is in the middle in your photograph.

Out of universe, the purple wigs were a design choice of Sylvia Anderson, intended to just be 'futuristic' and minimize the effort of doing individual hair styles.